# Observables and local observations in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wave-particle-duality, observables

I have recently taken a quantum field theory course at my university but it focused heavily on the mathematics of the theory and not the physics. So I am left with a few questions on observables and their local nature.

Second quantization gives us a field of operators with an operator associated to every point. However, most of the time, the field operator is not an observable because it is not hermitian and the number operator isn't well defined for interacting theories. So in an interacting theory, there is no way of telling how many particles are there in the universe or directly measuring a field. The only observables that I know of which are well defined in any type of theory are the components of the stress energy tensor (I am not familiar with spin so I am not including it here). **So would it be right to say that if given a box and asked whether a particle is present in it, the only way to do this is to measure the energy, momentum etc? If not, what other observables are well defined in QFT?**

My second question has to do with the locality of observations and their associated operators. Consider the case of the $T^{00}$ component of the stress energy tensor. Integrating this over a spatial hypersurface gives us the Hamiltonian $H = \int T^{00}d^3x$. The eigenvectors of this operator are possible states the universe (or the field) and it's eigenvalues are possible energies. However, since the Hamiltonian isn't local in the sense that it is not associated to any single point $x$ but is an integral, the energy is interpreted to be the energy of the entire hypersurface. **Using the same argument, would an operator such as $T^{00}(x)$ correspond to a local measurement of energy density at a point $x$? and are smeared operators interpreted as measurements within a fixed patch with the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian being essentially unobservable because it's physically impossible to measure energy non locally all across the hypersurface?**

Finally, the commutator of the components of the stress energy tensor at different points is zero for space-like separations and, I believe, takes some non-zero value within the future light-cone.  I guess this is more of a linear algebra question but this means that there is a basis which diagonalizes all $T^{00}(x)$ on our hypersurface. **However, is it possible to have a basis which diagonalizes only a specific $T^{00}(x)$ and not any other $T^{00}(x')$ on the hypersurface? In addition, is the right interpretation of the fact that the stress energy tensor commutes at different points is that the measurement of energy density at a local point $x$ can only affect the measurement within the light cone? So in a sense, it "collapses the wavefunction" within the light cone?**

Comment: Particles are only defined asymptotically which is why the most common observable people talk about is the S-matrix.

Comment: Fields are only distributions, hence a specific $T_{00}(x)$ is an ill-defined objects. You need to smear over a space-time region and take the Hermitian part to get true observables.

Comment: For measurement in quantum field theory, see Haag's book on local quantum field theory.